# jQuery hover one element, change css of another not working

Tags: jquery, hover

First, I realize that it seems this has been asked multiple times, and I have followed existing advice but do not get it working anyway.

See this codepen for a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nlGHo

I am trying to change the opacity of a div when hovering another div. In the demo, the background picture opacity for the two boxes on the right should change when hovering the white boxes. The jQuery I have is below. The divs `.box-content` are the white boxes, and divs `.opacity` create the opacity (opaque black overlay) for the background images. See the demo above to see the whole page. At the moment nothing happens when the white boxes are hovered. The `.next()`should target the next sibling element which is the div `.opacity`, if I am correct.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box-content').hover(function () {
        $(this).next().css('opacity', '0.2');
    }, function () {
        $(this).next().css('opacity', '0.5');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Vision</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mission</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Survey</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="footer">
        <hr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <ul class="contacts">
            <li>COMPANY NAME</li>
            <li>+1 336 123 4567</li>
            <li>company@email.com</li>
            <li>1709 address avenue</li>
        </ul>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="pic"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="opacity"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="pic"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CodePen isn't including jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your codepen you don't have jQuery loaded.
In this jsfiddle it works:

```
//Load jquery before
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.box-content').hover(function () {
    $(this).next().css('opacity', '0.2');
}, function () {
    $(this).next().css('opacity', '0.5');
});
```

});

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marioaraque/pzf88e42/)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your demo the HTML for the two sides of the experience aren't similar. In the one on the left you have a `DIV` with a class of 'opacity' on it but not on the right side. If you add that `DIV` to the right side you will see the effect happening on both sides.

Hovering over the left white `DIV` effects the left side and hovering over the right white `DIV` effects the right side. There's no need to change any of the JavaScript, and your HTML will look like this:

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Mission</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Survey</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="footer">
    <hr>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul class="contacts">
        <li>COMPANY NAME</li>
        <li>+1 336 123 4567</li>
        <li>company@email.com</li>
        <li>1709 address avenue</li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="pic"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="opacity"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-content">
            <div class="pic"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="opacity"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```